# ReactJs: Reading all the form input values when clicking on the submit button

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, forms, reactstrap

My form is made-up of multiple lines of this: 
[image]
This is the code:

```
   <Form>
              <Row form>
                <Col md={3}>
                  <FormGroup>
                    <Label for="element">Element</Label>
                    <Input type="text" name="element" id="element" />
                  </FormGroup>
                </Col>
                <Col md={3}>
                  <FormGroup>
                    <Label for="description">Description courte</Label>
                    <Input
                      type="text"
                      id="description"
                      name="description"
                    />
                  </FormGroup>
                </Col>
                <Col md={3}>
                  <FormGroup>
                    <Label for="coutUnitaire">Coût unitaire</Label>
                    <Input
                      type="text"
                      name="coutUnitaire"
                      id="coutUnitaire"
                    />
                  </FormGroup>
                </Col>
                <Col md={3}>
                  <FormGroup>
                    <Label for="quantite">Quantité</Label>
                    <Input type="text" name="quantite" id="quantite" />
                  </FormGroup>
                </Col>
              </Row>
              <Button
                color="primary"
                className="float-right"
                onClick={this.onDevisCreer}
              >
                Créer le devis
              </Button>
            </Form>
```

Usually, when it comes to retrieving values from a form I would use the value attribute and a listener:

```
   <Input
                        type="text"
                        id="noteText"
                        name="noteText"
                        type="textarea"
                        value={this.state.noteText}
                        onChange={this.onChange}
                        required
                      />
```

The listener:

```
  onChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    });
  }
```

However, since that line will be repeated many times, I cannot create a state property for each input (4 items per line* nbr of lines).

The final result that I want is an an array of objects, where each object contains the informations in one line of the form:

```
    // I need to create an array of this:
// {
//       element: "TC 100",
//       description: "Toner Cartridge",
//       quantite: 2,
//       coutUnitaire: 2,
//       total: coutUnitaire*quantite, // to be calculated
//     }
```

I still cannot see how can I retrieve the values of the inputs of the form, if I will not bind them to a state property like I usually would.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a way to get all values from the form. You would have to use [controlled input](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) (meaning you would need to use `value` with `onChange`).

The other way if you want to use [uncontrolled inputs](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html) is that you can assign `ref` for each input and then read the values on submit.

My suggestion would be to use the controlled inputs, make row as a new component and then use [React.memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) - so it will only re-render if there is an actual change in it. That is how I solved quite a few performance issues.

Comment: I don't see how that solves my problem. I don't see how I would retrieve the values

Comment: Sorry for that, I might have been a bit unclear above. I edited so it should be clearer.